# Cannot reinstall ubuntu desktop python3-minimal issue

Tags: 20.04, dependencies, python3

I crashed my system removing python. I tried to reinstall it but has issue with python3-minimal.
I searched many Stacks and tried that to fix.
Now I cannot access to GUI and reinstall it as reinstallation needs python3-minimal.

**Ubuntu 20.04 LTS amd64**

Here is output where it's crashes:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-minimal.postinst: /usr/bin/py3compile: /usr/bin/pyhton3: bad interpreter:
 No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure)
installed python3-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returne error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
python3-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg/ returned an error code (1)
```

Below I will mark this block as "**SAME**" to make the post more readable.

Then I tried all possible fixes which I could found:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`***SAME***

`sudo apt -f update`
***SAME***
`sudo apt install -f --reinstall python3-minimal`

```
1 not fully installed or removed
E: Internal Erorr, No file name for python3-minimal:amd64
```

Also tried reinstall dependencies [by this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064696/how-to-restore-after-accidentally-apt-get-remove-python)

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python python-chardet python-colorama python-distlib python-django python-django-tables2 python-six python-html5lib python-lxml python-minimal python-pkg-resources python-setuptools python-urllib3 python-requests python-pip python-virtualenv

Reading package list... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python-is-python2' instead of 'python'
Package python-urllib3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
is only available from another source

Package python-virtualenv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package python-colorama
E: Unable to locate package python-django
E: Unable to locate package python-django-tables2
E: Package 'python-urllib3' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package python-request
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
E: Package 'python-virtualenv' has no installation candidate
```

Also tried to autoremove, clean, purge and install again.***SAME***

Also tried to download .deb package and manually install it (also with aptitude)***SAME***

Please, let me know if I forgot give more clues.

***Extra question:*** Now I have installed and fully worked python2.7, can I in some way reinstall ubuntu with it?

***Update:*** I installed python3.3 & python3.9.5 source through wget, but this didn't help.
Here are some more clues:

```
namei $(which python3) $(which python)
f: /usr/bin/python
d /
d usr
d bin
d python3.9.5
d bin
-python 3.9

dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacke/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-====================-=================-======-==============================
ic python3               3.8.2-0ubuntu2    amd64  high-level object-oriented lan
iF python3-minimal       3.8.2-0ubuntu2    amd64  minimal subset of Python

whereis python
python: /usr/bin/pyhton2.7 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/lib/pyhton2.7 /etc/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/share/python /opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3 /opt/python3.3/bin/pyhton3.3-config /opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3m /opt/python3.3/bin/pyhton3.3m-config

whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3 /etc/python3 /usr/share/python3 /opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3 /opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3-config /opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3m /opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3m-config /usr/share/man/ma1/python3.1.gz
```

Comment: Don't use front-ends until you've installed `python3-minimal`, ie. you can't use `apt` & like tools that require python to be working correctly... use `wget` to download & `dpkg` to install...   (20.04 doesn't use `python2` so it won't help)

Comment: Thanks, @guiverc , will try it now

Comment: Execuse me, @guiverc, I tried your solution but again stuck... I downloaded python3.3 and python3.9.5 successfully but system still needs python3-minimal. As I get - if I have working python3 - I already have minimal. If it's so, then what am I doing wrong? py3compiler want's links  exactly in /usr/bin/python3 ? Can you please write in details what should I do? (also I can't find sourse url to exactly python3-minimal, only to packeges)

Comment: I can only guess (as I don't know exactly what you did), but if you made changes in attempts to make different versions of python/python3 the default; those changes need to be reversed. Apt logs (/var/log/apt/history.log) will provide reminders, as will bash logs (if you used commands) but python being stuffed up is usually fixed fastest by re-install (no format) as it needs to be working for many of our normal tools to work...

Comment: `namei $(which python3) $(which python)` please add this to your question. and also `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`

Comment: Thank you @nobody, I added more info.